# How do I combine these three sets of code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have three radio buttons. The code behind their change events is as follows:

```
    private void uxRajRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (uxRajRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            uxPersonBettingLabel.Text = "Raj";
            GuySelected = 0;
            uxBetNumericUpDown.Maximum =  Guys[GuySelected].Cash;
        }
    }
    private void uxPaulRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (uxPaulRadioButton.Checked == true) 
        {
            uxPersonBettingLabel.Text = "Paul";
            GuySelected = 1;
            uxBetNumericUpDown.Maximum = Guys[GuySelected].Cash;
        }
    }
    private void uxMikeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (uxMikeRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            uxPersonBettingLabel.Text = "Mike";
            GuySelected = 2;
            uxBetNumericUpDown.Maximum = Guys[GuySelected].Cash;
        }
    }
```

With just three radio buttons this is acceptable but if I had say 7 radio buttons each with 20 lines of code behind its change event then it would be a lot of (needless?) code. I've attempted to shorten the above and ended up with the following. Is this correct?

```
     private void uxRajRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
         radioButtonCode(this.uxRajRadioButton, 0);
     }
    private void uxPaulRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        radioButtonCode(this.uxPaulRadioButton,1);
    }
    private void uxMikeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        radioButtonCode(this.uxMikeRadioButton, 2);
    }

    int GuySelected=0;
    public void radioButtonCode(RadioButton myRadio, int mybettorIndex)
    {
        if (myRadio.Checked == true)
        {
            GuySelected = mybettorIndex;
            uxPersonBettingLabel.Text = Guys[GuySelected].Name;
            uxBetNumericUpDown.Maximum = Guys[GuySelected].Cash;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you have the same event handler for all the radio buttons? Something like

```
private void uxRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     radioButtonCode((RadioButton)sender);
}

public void radioButtonCode(RadioButton myRadio)
{
    if (myRadio.Checked == true)
    {
        int guySelected = getGuySelectedIndex(myRadio);
        uxPersonBettingLabel.Text = Guys[guySelected].Name;
        uxBetNumericUpDown.Maximum = Guys[guySelected].Cash;
    }
}

public int getGuySelectedIndex(RadioButton myRadio)
{
    int index = 0;
    if (myRadio == this.uxRajRadioButton) index = 0;
    else if (myRadio == this.uxPaulRadioButton) index = 1;
    else if (myRadio == this.uxMikeRadioButton) index = 2;
    return index;
}
```

Comment: +1 ok - very nice - never quite understood the "sender" parameter. so I could then just add this event procedure _uxRadioButton_CheckedChanged_ to each of the change events in the properties window in VS - nice.

Comment: not quite working ... it doesn't like the following `radioButtonCode(sender);` and I understand why as `sender` is an object but the method `radioButtonCode` parameter is a RadioButton. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Oops, missed the cast, glad you got it. I like @VoidStar's answer in that he combined the uxRadioButton_CheckedChanged and radioButtonCode functions together, there's no real reason to have them separate IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code sample, where you have extracted the commonalities out to a function looks like the way I would have done this refactoring.

It is about as good as you can make it, barring the name (`UpdateUserInfo` might be slightly better).

Comment: thanks Oded - there are a few other ways of _skinning the cat_ in amongst the answers, but if you are relatively happy with my code then I'll pretty much leave it as is.

Comment: @whytheq - I am not the be all and end all of answers... Take a look at the other options, and if you like the skinning method better, go with it ;)

Comment: I'm trying to use zever's amswer below - can you see the comment I've added - how do I get his code to work? if I change the method parameter to type `object` then I get other errors?!

Comment: @whytheq - try to cast the `sender`: `radioButtonCode((RadioButton)sender);`.

Comment: will do. I'd tried sending an object and then in the method creating a new variable myRad and having `RadioButton myRad = (RadioButton)myRadio;`. This ran but had some unexpected results. I'll follow your advice and cast in the `CheckedChanged` method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way. Declare an array of radio buttons and bind them to above event at run time. This binding code won't be inside designer page. This will result in single `ArrayRadio_checkedChange` event. In this method you can use sender property to figure out the proper radio button's index and take action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
uxRajRadioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rb_CheckedChanged);
uxPaulRadioButton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rb_CheckedChanged);
...

uxRajRadioButton.Tag =new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Raj",0);
uxPaulRadioButton.Tag =new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Paul",1);
....

private void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(!(sender is RadioButton))
         return;
       RadioButton myRadio= sender as RadioButton;
      if (myRadio.Checked == true)
      {
        myRadio.Text = (myRadio.Tag as KeyValuePair<string,int>).Key;
        GuySelected = (myRadio.Tag as KeyValuePair<string,int>).Value;
        uxBetNumericUpDown.Maximum =  Guys[GuySelected].Cash;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I put the index in the tag attribute. This way you can bind this event to every RadioButton

```
public void uxRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton myRadio = (RadioButton) sender;
    if (myRadio.Checked)
    {
        GuySelected = (int)myRadio.Tag;
        uxPersonBettingLabel.Text = Guys[GuySelected].Name;
        uxBetNumericUpDown.Maximum = Guys[GuySelected].Cash;
    }
}
```